# Find entropy in WEKA

Tags: feature-selection, entropy, weka

I am working on FAST feature selection algorithm and for that I need to find entropy of each attribute in dataset. But the obstacle is I need to find it in WEKA library.

Does anyone have any idea where I can find code for WEKA(for any algorithm which calculates entropy of every attribute)?

Comment: For Weka questions, ask on the Wekalist. Usually, the authors of Weka give a good answer very fast there...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to compute Shannon entropy, which is $H(X)=E(-log(P(X))$. In the case of a nominal/discrete variable the plug in estimator of the probability for your sample is the fraction of samples. Thus, suppose your $X$ variable is a nominal variable with $K$ classes, the plug in estimate of the probability that $X=k$, for $K=[1,K]$ is given by:

$$P(X=k) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{I(x_i=k)}{N} = \frac{\#|X=k|}{\#|X|}$$

which in plain English is the number of instances equals with $k$ divided by the total number of instances.

Now if you expand the expected value formula, you will have:

$$H(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{K} -P(X=k)log(P(X=k)) = - \sum_{i=1}^{K}\frac{\#|X=k|}{\#|X|}log(\frac{\#|X=k|}{\#|X|})$$

From here you simply have to count the number of instances for each $k$ from your set.

As you can see the formula is pretty straightforward. In weka you have weka.core.ContingencyTables class, which contains some methods for computing entropy. Among them there is a method called entropy which receives an array of doubles as parameter. This array of doubles you have to provide it and contains the number of instances for each $k$ (as a matter of consequence, the vector has $k$ elements). Hope it helps.